# Python Tkinter, How do I get the subitems of an Item in Tkinter TreeView?

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

how can I get the Subitems of an item in a Tkinter TreeView?

```
-Item
|-Subitem1
||-Subsubitem1  \ This two items
||-Subsubitem2  /
|-Subitem2
|-Subitem3
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command is [`tree.get_children(item=None)`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/tkinter.ttk.html#tkinter.ttk.Treeview.get_children). You can call it recursively to go through the child nodes.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
tree = ttk.Treeview(root)

a = tree.insert("", "end", text="Item",open=True)
b = tree.insert(a, "end", text="Subitem1",open=True)
tree.insert(a, "end", text="Subitem2")

for i in range(1,3):
    tree.insert(b, "end", text=f"Subsubitem{i}")

tree.pack()

def get_child():
    for item in tree.get_children():
        for subitem in tree.get_children(item):
            for subsubitem in tree.get_children(subitem):
                print (subsubitem, tree.item(subsubitem)["text"])

tk.Button(root,text="click me",command=get_child).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for!